# How to hide "./" in netrw vim

Tags: vim, netrw

I'm looking for a way to hide `./` from the Explore list in netrw. I was hoping to use a vim regex, but I can't land the proper one.

My current ignore list is:

```
let g:netrw_list_hide= '.*\.swp$,.DS_Store,*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip,*.git'
```

And according to [`:help netrw-gitignore`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-gitignore):

> Files that do not exist, are ignored.
>   Git-ignore patterns are taken from existing files, and converted to patterns for
>   hiding files. For example, if you had '*.log' in your '.gitignore' file, it
>   would be converted to '.*\.log'.

But this doesn't translate to the specific path. How do I hide `./` in netrw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I lifted this, `^\.\.\=/\=$`, from Tim Pope's [vinegar.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar)

```
let g:netrw_list_hide= '.*\.swp$,.DS_Store,*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip,*.git,^\.\.\=/\=$'
```